# How to bind named parameter from dto in native query in Spring data jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-el

Is it possible to bind parameter from dto in sppring data jpa native sql?

Here example. I have native sql with a lot of parametr

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_very_usefull_field_tbl")
@NamedNativeQuery(
        name = INSERT_IGNORE_CONFLICT,
        query = "INSERT INTO my_very_usefull_field_tbl\n" +
                "(\n" +
                "   field1, \n" +
                ...
                "   field50, \n" +
                ")\n" +
                "VALUES(\n" +
                "  :fieldDto.field1,\n" +
            ...
            "  :fieldDto.field50 -- modify_author\n" +
                ") on conflict do nothing;"
)
public class MyVeryUsefullFieldEntity {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "field1")
    private String field1;

    @Column(name = "field2")
    private String field2;
    
    ...
    
    @Column(name = "field50")
    private String field50;

}



public interface MyVeryUsefullFieldRepository extends CrudRepository<MyVeryUsefullFieldEntity, String> {

    String INSERT_IGNORE_CONFLICT = "INSERT_IGNORE_CONFLICT";
   
    @Modifying
    @Query(name = INSERT_IGNORE_CONFLICT, nativeQuery = true)
    int insertIgnoreConflict(@Param("fieldDto") MyVeryUsefullFieldDto fieldDto);
    
}
```

Everything work fine when if I specify each flild in `MyVeryUsefullFieldRepository#insertIgnoreConflict` method (50 input parameters). But method with a lot parameter looks terrible. I want to reffer to dto field inside sql and pass dto into `insertIgnoreConflict` method. But nothing worked for me. I try to bind like example above. Not worked. I try to bind throw spell `:#{#fieldDto.field1}`. Application not started with exception: `Space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':'`.

Can anyone give me some advice on how to do it?

Comment: Why not use OOP aproach? Map with data mapper and save. Using a native querry is a very slippery slope, must be a good reason for that; If you will grow them, a project will be very difficult to support in time. But if you still look for a solution in this context, you will have to summon the entity manager and instead of naming static querry use dynamic approach. Take a look https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query#1-example-of-a-dynamic-query